# SwiftUI: Picker content does not display when selected in a list

Tags: list, macos, swiftui, picker

I am trying to make a list of selectionable rows in Swift UI, the rows including a Picker. Everything works fine, except that the content of the Picker disappears when selected, see attached screenshot (but is actually visible when the window of the app is not active (i.e. when I click on another window))

[image: screenshot showing the problem]

I tried everything I could think of, I could not solve this issue. Below a minimal code to reproduce the problem. Anyone has any idea, how to get around this problem

SelectionList.swift

```
struct SelectionList: View {
    @State var dudes: [String] = ["Tim", "Craig", "Phil"]
    @State var selectedRow = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
              
        return List(selection: $selectedRow) {
            ForEach(self.dudes, id: \.self) { item in
                SelectionRow()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SelectionRow.swift

```
struct SelectionRow: View {
    
    @State var selectedFruit = 0
    
    let fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears"]
  
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: self.$selectedFruit, label: EmptyView()) {
            ForEach(0 ..< fruits.count, id: \.self) {
               Text(self.fruits[$0])
            }
        }
    }
}
```